# In MCMC, why can throwing only initial data away improve the estimate?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

**UPDATED**
I'm leaning MCMC by myself and facing the concept of `burn-in` now.
Some articles said `burn-in` can improve the estimate. Why does throwing away initial data work for improving the estimate?

Comment: Burn-in is used to remove the "redundant" values in the chain *before* the chain converges. Essentially, these points are deemed to not actually be draws from the posterior distribution. It's filtering to improve your estimate. Burn-in isn't specifically related to the convergence of the chain itself.

Comment: @StatsPlease I see! Thank you for your pointing out. Then what makes MCMC convergent? Also do I need to change the question as why `burn-in` can improve the estimate? ?

Comment: I would try raising a separate question related specifically to convergence of MCMC. But remember to check the site for other existing questions which might address this already. I think there are quite a few already.

Comment: @StatsPlease OK! I'll do!

Comment: @Yuki The first "MC" in MCMC relates to what is converging -- (in a suitably designed sampling scheme)  the joint distribution of the things being sampled converge to sampling the stationary distribution of a Markov Chain.

Comment: @Glen_b So did you mean sampling matters for MCMC's convergence ?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking but I was discussing *[convergence of Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Steady-state_analysis_and_limiting_distributions)*, not sampling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without proposing here a complete recap of Markov chain Monte Carlo methods, let me point out that the fundamental concept behind these methods is that they converge to the distribution $\pi^\star(\cdot)$ they aim at simulating, rather than simulating values from that distribution from the start of the method (as in, e.g., accept-reject algorithms). This means that the simulated Markov chain $(X^{(t)})_t$ is such that

1. $X^{(0)}$ is distributed from an arbitrary distribution with density $\pi_0(\cdot)$ as for instance a Normal distribution (or a Dirac mass at 0);
2. $X^{(1)}$ is distributed from a distribution $\pi_0(\cdot)$ that is not $\pi^\star(\cdot)$ but the transform of $\pi_0(\cdot)$ via the Markov kernel of the MCMC algorithm, $K$, namely$$\pi_1(x)=\int_\mathcal X\pi_0(\text{d}y)K(y,x)$$
   $$\vdots$$

   4.$X^{(t)}$ is distributed from a distribution $\pi_0(\cdot)$ that is not $\pi(\cdot)$ but the transform of $\pi_0(\cdot)$ via the Markov kernel of the MCMC algorithm, $K$, applied $t$ times, namely$$\pi_t(x)=\int_\mathcal X\pi_0(\text{d}y)K^t(y,x)$$

The chain $(X^{(t)})_t$ is furthermore **ergodic** which means that, *no matter what $\pi_0$ is*, the distribution $\pi_t$ does converge to the target $\pi^\star$. This means, that, asymptotically, $X^{(t)}$ is distributed from$\pi^\star$ and also that an average like$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T h(X^{(t)})\tag{1}$$ converges to $\mathbb E^{\pi^\star}[h(X)]$ no matter what $\pi_0$ is (Ergodic Theorem).

Then what is burning (or warmup) intended to do? It is there to remove the strong influence or bias of the starting values of the chain $(X^{(t)})_t$ on the starting distribution $\pi_0$ that slows down convergence of (1) to $\mathbb E^{\pi^\star}[h(X)]$. In loose terms, it means waiting till the chain $(X^{(t)})_t$ has "reached stationarity", i.e., the time when $\pi_t$ is almost equal to $\pi^star$.

Here is a toy example where the target is
$$\pi^star\propto x^2\underbrace{\varphi(x-4)}_\text{normal density}$$ and the Metropolis-Hastings proposal is
$$K(x,y)=\underbrace{\mathfrak t_5(y-x)}_\text{$\mathfrak T_5$ density}$$

[image: 10 MCMC chains started from a Normal distribution]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm99Eh.jpg)

where 10 MCMC chains are started from a standard Normal distribution and take a little while to reach a stationary regime and region where they all behave the same. The burning would thus be 20 or 30 in that case. But starting with a much more widespread initial distribution shows the difference in the impact on the values of the chains:

[image]

However, removing the first iterations also remove the reduction in Monte Carlo variability which may mean that it is not always worthwhile, as shown by the comparison below for the approximation of $\mathbb E^{\pi^\star}[X^2]$ without and with burning (29 off):

[image: ![![enter image description here]